# Is possible to force a Firebase Crashlytics report to be uploaded immediately after a crash occurs?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am using FirebaseCrashlytics to log exception manually with `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)` but as a request from my PO, I need this exception to be uploaded immediately after this line. Is this possible?
On the docs, I've found the method `sendUnsentReports()` but this doesn't look to work, I also checked right after record an exception if there is any unsent report using `checkForUnsentReports()` but the result of the task is true only if I close and reopen the app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409353/firebase-sendunsentreports-sends-exceptions-only-after-restart

Comment: @OlegKodysh Thanks this behavior makes too much sense!

Comment: @OlegKodysh make this comment an answer and I will mark this answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As linked here: [firebase sendUnsentReports() sends exceptions only after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409353/firebase-sendunsentreports-sends-exceptions-only-after-restart)

Logged exceptions are not sent immediately when they are recorded. They are batched and sent either on startup or at crash time. Calling sendUnsentReports, will cause cached reports to be sent at that time, but it will not send anything from the current session.